# PyInstaller: How to call "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" file with dlib.shape_predictor, while imported it with 'binaries'?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have an small app, which is used `face_recognition` library.
And I already imported it with

```
face_models = [
('.//face_recognition_models//models//dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat', 
'./face_recognition_models/models'),
('.//face_recognition_models//models//mmod_human_face_detector.dat', 
'./face_recognition_models/models'),
('.//face_recognition_models//models//shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat', 
'./face_recognition_models/models'),
('.//face_recognition_models//models//shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat', 
'./face_recognition_models/models'),
]

 a = Analysis(['logic.py'],
         pathex=[],
         binaries=face_models,
         ...
```

in the `logic.spec` file. This means that my `.exe` already contain `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` file. (I build it with `--onefile` param and it work perfectly). But when I tried to import the same `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks` file with `dlib.shape_predictor` I got the `RuntimeError: Unable to open models/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`.

So, my question is how can I import `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` file with `dlib.shape_predictor`? (It should be already included in `exe`..)

Peace of code:

```
import dlib

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks. dat')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as possible:

We can use `face_recognition.face_landmarks` function instead to get landmarks.